# Scroll bar closes drop down list in Internet Explorer

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, mean-stack

I am working on a mean stack application, where I am creating a drop down using following directive :

```
.directive('inputDropdown', function($compile) {

    var template = 
        '<input class="form-control" ng-model="ngModel">' +
        '<div class="dropdown">' + 
            '<div class="form-control" ng-repeat="value in list | filter:ngModel">' +
                '<div ng-mousedown="select($event, value)">{{value}}</div>' + 
            '</div>' +
        '</div>';

    return {
        restrict: 'EA',
        require: '^form',
        scope: {
            ngModel: '=',
            list: '=',
            onSelect: '&'
        },
        template: template,
        link: function(scope, element, attrs,mapController) {
            element.addClass('input-dropdown');
            scope.select = function(e, value) {
                scope.ngModel = value;
                scope.onSelect({$event: e, value: value});
                scope.makeFormDirty = mapController.$setDirty();
            };
        }
    };
})
```

and then using this directive in my html as :

```
<input-dropdown name="fqn" ng-model="modelVariables" list="variables"></input-dropdown>
```

This code works absolutely fine on chrome but when it comes to Internet Explorer(version 11) the drop down comes as expected but when I try to click the scroll bar of drop down it closes it. What change should I do to this directive so that it don't closes the drop down and user should be able to scroll using scroll bars.

Comment: (try `<div input-dropdown ... ></div>` syntax with IE)

Comment: @AlekseySolovey not working